# Calculating value in input field

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create an input field with two buttons, which will add and distract number in an input field by 1.

All works fine but when I try to change number directly in input field, buttons stop working

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.Score1 = 0;

  $scope.$watch('Score1', function (newVal) {
    $scope.Score1 = newVal;
    console.log(newVal);
  });

  $scope.add_btn = function() {
    $scope.Score1 ++;
  };

  $scope.dist_btn = function() {
    if ($scope.Score1 > 0) {
      $scope.Score1 --;
    } else {
      $scope.Score1 = 0;
    }
  };
}
```

```css
</style> <!-- Ugly Hack due to jsFiddle issue: http://goo.gl/BUfGZ --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
```

```html
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
          <button ng-click="add_btn()">+</button>
              <input type="text" value="{{Score1}}">  
          <button ng-click="dist_btn()">-</button>
</div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/g9opLkce/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ng-model`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) to bind the input ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7nowxfz8/)):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Score1">
```